# How to save or push to observable with AngularFire2 FirebaseObjectObservale

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angularfire2

For some reason I cannot wrap my head around the methods in angularfire2 and firebaseobjectobservables and rxjs. I tried using $save() but I get an error about it not existing on firebaseobjectobservables. I also tried .push() which also brought up an error. Am I not importing something?

```
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

  private Room:FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;


 constructor(private af:AngularFire, private http:Http) {
  this.Room=af.database.object(`/Rooms/1`);
}

  //This is where the error pops up
 this.Room.push({name:abc,room:1}).then((item) => { console.log(item.key); });

  //Here is my other version trying to use firbase method $save() w/ the same error
  this.Room.$save(this.playerO).then(_ => console.log("Pushed"));
```

Comment: You should use set or update as stated in the docs https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md

Comment: I will try this now

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You have to push room item to your room list and room key will be autogenerated.

```
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';

export class Room {
   private Rooms:FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

   constructor(private af:AngularFire) {
     this.Rooms=af.database.list('/Rooms');
     this.Rooms.push({name:'abc'}).then((room) => { console.log(room.key); });
   }
}
```